# Intersection of a Poisson bridge and a Brownian bridge

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Take a Poisson process $N_t$, a Brownian motion $W_t$ and constants $T > 0$ and $a > 0$. Suppose $N$ and $W$ are independent. I'm interested in the probability that $W$ does not cross over $a + N_t$ during the interval $[0,T]$. To this end, I want to first calculate the above probability conditioned on $N_T = n$ and $W_T = x$, $(x < n)$.

Thus I want to calculate
$$ 
P\bigl(W_t < a + N_t , \forall t \leq T \; \bigl| \;  W_T = x, N_T = n \bigl).
$$

Given that the conditioned on $N_T$, the jump times of $N$ are uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,T]$, and that the average path of the Poisson bridge is simply the straight line joining the points $(0,a)$ and $(T,n)$, my intuition is that this conditional probability will end up being the same as the probability that the Brownian bridge between $(0,0)$ and $(T,x)$ remains below the straight line joining $(0,a)$ and $(T,n)$.

Can someone suggest a way to approach this problem?

Comment: Is it correct that you assume that $N$ and $W$ are independent processes? Otherwise nothing can be concluded.

Comment: @DieterKadelka yes, I forgot to mention that. I'll put that in now. Thank you.

Comment: I found a result by Perry, Stadje and Zacks that calculates an integral equation satisfied by the distribution of first meeting time of a Brownian motion and an independent compound Poisson process (not bridges). I can't easily deduce my conjecture from there. 

I guess I could adapt their argument to come up with a new integral equation, but I foresee difficulties.

Comment: (1/2) What you are after is the probability $q(a,t)$ that the Lévy process $X_t := W_t - N_t$ does not exceed level $a$ up to time $t$. This is the fundamental question studied in *fluctuation theory of Lévy processes*. Usually, things get pretty complicated here, and unless you are extremely lucky, explicit expressions are not available. A general approach is as follows. The bi-variate Laplace transform of $q(a,t)$ is given by the Pecherskii–Rogozin identity in terms of Wiener–Hopf factors. These are usually given in an integral form only. Nevertheless, it is sometimes possible...

Comment: (2/2) ...to invert the Laplace transform and get a reasonable expression for $q(t,a)$. If you are interested, I can provide some entry points to literature, and, time permitting, have a look and see if there is any hope for workable expressions for this particular process.

Comment: Hi Mateusz. Yes that probability can be derived easily from the Kendall's identity. In fact, writing $\tau_x$ as first passage time of $X$ over level $x$, $f(t,x)dx = P(X_t \in dx)$ and $g(t,x)dt = P(\tau_x \in dt)$, we have $g(t,x) = x f(t,x)/t$.

Comment: Developing this, in our case when the Levy process has a non-zero diffusion component, $f$ is a convolution of normal density $\phi$ and Poisson or some other infinitely divisible distribution $H$: $f(t,x) = \int \phi(t,x-y) H(t,dy)$, so that by Kendall, $g(t,x) = \int x \phi(t,x-y) / t H(t,dy)$. The integrand $x \phi(t, x-y )/t$ is the first passage density of Brownian motion over the STRAIGHT LINE through points $(0,x)$ and $(t, x-y)$. This is where the straight line intuition in my question came from. I was hoping to find an independent proof.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki and of course, I forgot to mention, Kendall's identity only holds when level crossing occurs continuously, i.e., without overshoots (with probability 1), which is indeed the case in my setting. More generally, Kendall holds for spectrally negative (positive) processes with non-lattice distributions crossing a level boundary from below (above).

Classical result - I know of at least 4 proofs.

Comment: @zab: Ah, I thought you meant a two-sided Poisson process. For the one-sided, of course Kendall's identity applies. I'll think about the "alternative proof" question and will get back if I have anything insightful to add.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you. I took the liberty to send you an email.